# button image drawn at random upon button click in the group in the expandlistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an expandlistview in which I have included a button on the the group.  When I click on the button, it is supposed to save the data associated with the button and also it has to redraw the button, based on the value of the button.  The issue I am having is that it is not only redrawing itself but also it is redrawing some other buttons.  It is quite difficult to understand and explain what is happening as it seems to redraw any button it at random.  **Please note that the save part is working correctly.**

Can anyone tell me, what could be wrong with the piece of code below.  **The only thing I want to achieve is redraw the button that is being clicked only and not any other button in the expandlistview.**

```
 groupHolder.Favourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String itemKey = Holder.Favourite.getTag().toString();
            Boolean starred = Client.data.get(itemKey.toLowerCase());
            Client.writeStarred(view.getContext(), itemKey.toLowerCase(), starred);

            if (starred)
                ((ImageButton) view).setImageDrawable(view.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_cat_star_yellow));
            else
                ((ImageButton) view).setImageDrawable(view.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_cat_star));
        }
    });
```

Part of the getGroupView

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GroupViewHolder Holder;
        final GroupEvent group = (GroupEvent) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (group.Starred)
            Holder.Favourite.setImageDrawable(convertView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_cat_star_yellow));
});
```

---

I have changed the code to the following to add notifyDataSetChanged(); , but this too does not seem to work.

```
groupHolder.ButtonFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String itemKey = gpHolder.ButtonFavourite.getTag().toString();
            Boolean starred = Client.data.get(itemKey.toLowerCase());
            Client.writeStarred(view.getContext(), itemKey.toLowerCase(), starred);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view is redrawing buttons at random due to view recycling.

For adapter views, the event handlers should be used to update model state and `getView()` [or for `ExpandableListView`, `getGroupView()` and `getChildView()`] should render the views based on that state.

In `getGroupView()`, check the starred flag for the item and set your image drawable accordingly.

Make sure you treat your view as "dirty" since it may be recycled and explicitly set the image drawable value every time:

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    GroupViewHolder Holder;
    final GroupEvent group = (GroupEvent) getGroup(groupPosition);
    ...
    Holder.Favourite.setImageDrawable(convertView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(
        group.Starred ? R.drawable.ic_cat_star_yellow : R.drawable.ic_cat_star));                
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kris larson, can you give me an example how to do this, I have added the GetView code .  How do I do the the set the flag that the item has been starred and  notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I have added the notifyDataSetChanged(); but this does not seem to redraw the groups...

Comment: See my updated answer.  You should use `onGroupClick()` instead, and also explicitly set the drawable in `getGroupView()` since the view may be recycled.

Comment: larsion, I don`t want to set the image based on groupclick, rather, I want it on the imagebutton click.  They are 2 completely different things... groupclick and itemclick don`t give the same result

Comment: Okay, I removed the `onGroupClick()` part of the answer.  You have `notifyDataSetChanged()`, you are checking the flag in `getGroupView()`, so now I think all you need is that last line of code in my answer.